# Transfer files using checksums only?

Tags: math, checksum

Would it be possible to transfer large files using only a system of checksums, and then reconstruct the original file by calculations?

Say that you transfer the MD5 checksum of a file and the size of the file. By making a "virtual file" and calculating it's checksum, trying every single bit combination, you should eventually "reach" the original file. But on the way you would also get a lot of "collisions" where the checksum also match.

So we change the first byte of the original file to some specified value, calculate the checksum again, and send this too. If we make the same substitution in the virtual file we can test each "collision" to see if it still matches. This should narrow it down a bit, and we can do this several times.

Of course, the computing power to do this would be enormous. But is it theoretically possible, and how many checksums would you need to transfer something (say 1mb)? Or would perhaps the amount of data needed to transfer the checksums almost as large as the file, making it pointless?

Comment: MD5 is supposed to be one-way.

Comment: MD5 does have collisions. (Wang and Yu 2009)

Comment: All hash algorithms have collisions (pidgeonhole principle). That result just allows one to generate colliding pairs efficiently; however there's still no preimage attack (reversing MD5 from an arbitrary hash value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of data you need to transfer would most certainly be the same size as the file. Consider: If you could communicate a `n` byte file with `n-1` bytes of data, that means you've got `256^(n-1)` possible patterns of data you may have sent, but are selecting from a space of size `256^n`. This means that one out of every 256 files won't be expressible using this method - this is often referred to as the [pidegonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Now, even if that wasn't a problem, there's no guarentee that you won't have a collision after any given amount of checksumming. Checksum algorithms are designed to avoid collisions, but for most checksum/hash algorithms there's no strong proof that after X hashes you can guarantee no collisions in a N-byte space.

Finally, hash algorithms, at least, are designed to be hard to reverse, so even if it were possible it would take an impossible huge amount of CPU power to do so.

That said, for a *similar* approach, you might be interested in reading about [Forward Error Correction codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) - they're not at all hash algorithms, but I think you may find them interesting.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a problem of information. A checksum is not necessarily unique to a particular set of data, in fact to be so it would effectively need to have a many bits of information as the source. What it can indicate is that the data received is not the exact data that the checksum was generated from but in most cases it can't prove it.

Comment: Checksums can prove that your data is damaged. They can't prove that it's _not_ damaged :)

Comment: @thkala, which is exactly what I said :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not in any meaningfull form.

Long answer:

Let us assume an arbitrary file `file.bin` with a 1000-byte size. There are `2^(8*1000)` different combinations that could be its actual contents. By sending e.g. a 1000-bit checksum,
you still have about `2^(7*1000)` colliding alternatives.

By sending a single additional bit, you might be able cut those down by half... and you still have `2^6999` collisions. By the time you eliminate the colisions, you will have sent at least 8000 bits i.e. an amount equal or greater to the file size.

The only way for this to be theoretically possible (Note: I did not say "feasible", let alone "practical") would be if the file did not really contain random data and you could use that knowledge to prune alternatives. In that case you'd be better off using compression, ayway. Content-aware compression algorithms (e.g. [FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lossless_Audio_Codec) for audio) use a-priori knowledge on the properties of the input data to improve the compression ratio.

Answer (score 0):

In short "no".

To take a hypothetical example, consider a 24 bpp photo with 6 pixels -- there are 2^(24 * 6) (2^144) possible combinations of intensities for each colour channel on those six pixels, so you can gaurantee that if you were to evaluate every possibility, you are guaranteed an MD5 collision (as MD5 is a 128 bit number).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are thinking of is in fact an interesting topic, but you haven't hit upon the right method. If I can try and rephrase your question, you are asking if there is a way to apply a function to some data, transmit the result of the function, and then reconstruct the original data from the terser function result. For a single MD5 checksum the answer is no, but with other functions, provided you are willingly to send several function results, it is possible. In general this area of research is called [compressed sensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing). Sometimes exact reconstruction is possible, but more often it is used as a lossy compression scheme for images and other visual or sound data.